# LED Power Box Design

Tags: led, driver, low-voltage

I am designing an LED power supply unit, using off-the-shelf constant current drivers (Phillips Xitanium). The system will include a 0-10v dimmer, and I need to connect the Xitanium to both 120v for input, the low-voltage output to the LEDs and the 0-10v from the dimmer (which also takes 120v input to control shut-off of the line voltage). My supply unit will be constructed from 1/16" aluminum sheet metal.

In an earlier design I put a standard 4X4X1.5 junction box inside my power supply unit, but that makes it much larger than I need. I have less than 8 18W wires to connect typically, so this seems like real overkill. The Xitanium drivers are only 3X4X1.1 inches, so it would be great if I can keep the 120v connections the same depth (1.25" deep) and not take up too much space for the 120v connections. This will make it much easier for me to size the box for my needs. Ultimately I will want to get UL approval for this unit. The circuit for hooking up the drivers is trivial, I just want to be sure my physical design is correct.

My questions are:

Do I need to encase the 120v separately from the low-voltage wiring if it is all the same gauge wire, and it is all inside my metal case?

If I do need to keep the 120v connections separate from the low-voltage wires inside the box, then can I use a smaller metal box that I build inside the unit? How big does it need to be? Does this follow the NEC 3.12 guidelines of so much volume per wire?

Comment: By "18W", do you mean AWG 18?

Comment: Yes, 18 AWG wire. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In looking at the problem more, we found that the LED driver we want to use has the 120v and 0-10v dimming circuit on a single input end of the driver. It does not seem like isolation in that case is possible. If the 120v and 0-10v circuits are in a single chamber is that adequate? Then the low-voltage output would be in another isolated part of the box.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to just install a box cover inside the case, that should meet NEC requirements as long as we have enough cubic inches for the number of conductors contained.